# PHP not working : Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu

I have a problem my test server loads html files fine but when  I try to open a file like index.php it says `The website encountered an error while retrieving http://localhost/. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.` I have PHP5 installed but I don't see why this isn't working, is it an outdated PHP problem?

```
[Wed Sep 25 16:53:10 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/callum/public_html/Includes/Connection.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/callum/public_html/index.php on line 8
[Wed Sep 25 16:53:10 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/callum/public_html/Includes/Connection.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/callum/public_html/index.php on line 8
[Wed Sep 25 16:54:51 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/callum/public_html/Includes/Connection.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/callum/public_html/index.php on line 8
[Wed Sep 25 16:54:51 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/callum/public_html/Includes/Connection.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/callum/public_html/index.php on line 8
```

site config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /home/callum/public_html/
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/callum/public_html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Look at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`: vi /var/log/apache2/error.log and post it.

Comment: Added the error log

Answer (score 1):

It is a permissions issue. Just change the permissions:

```
sudo chmod 0644 /home/callum/public_html/Includes/Connection.php
```

and try again.

Comment: Didn't work, it made it worse. Said forbidden so I changed back to 0755

Comment: Ok. Go to your php.ini file: `cd /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` and comment the line `include_path...`. Restart the server and try again.

Comment: It was already commented ; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
;include_path = ".:/usr/share/php"

Comment: Add the apache site configuration to your question: `vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` or the name of your site configuration.

Comment: Added the sites config

Comment: How do you include this file `/home/callum/public_html/Includes/Connection.php`? I guess it is the problem.

Comment: like so require_once(__DIR__."/Includes/Connection.php");

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
require_once(DIR."/Includes/Connection.php");
```

Use this:

```
require_once("Includes/Connection.php");
```

Comment: Nope still get this failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: Is the error the same at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`?

Comment: I've fixed it now, sorry for any inconvenience. THe problem is that the file access wasn't set.

Comment: Could you specify?